# Power of a wave in a string

Tags: energy, waves, power

My text of physics, Gettys', shows how the energy, both kinetic and potential, of a small element $\Delta x$ of a string, through which a wave (whose wave function is $y:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $(x,t)\mapsto y(x,t)$) runs, is:

$$\Delta E=\Big[ \frac{1}{2}\mu\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{2}F\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Big)^2 \Big]\Delta x$$

where $\mu$ is the linear density of the string and $F$ is its tension. Opportune approximations are made to get this result.

By using an explicit notation for the variables, letting $x-x_0:=\Delta x$, I would say that the formula means$$E(x)-E(x_0)=\Big[ \frac{1}{2}\mu\Big(\frac{\partial y(x_0,t_0)}{\partial t}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{2}F\Big(\frac{\partial y(x_0,t_0)}{\partial x}\Big)^2 \Big](x-x_0)$$Everything clear to me until here.
Then, from the formula, my book infers that "the energy propagates along the string with velocity $v=\Delta x/\Delta t$" and "the power of th wave is $P=(\Delta E/\Delta x)(\Delta x/\Delta t)$" i.e.
$$P=v\Big[ \frac{1}{2}\mu\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{2}F\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Big)^2 \Big]$$
but I do not understand this step, because I do not understand what $\Delta x/\Delta t$ really is... I mean: the $x$ in the expression of $\Delta E$ is not a function of time and $\Delta E$ is defined for any choice of $x$, $x_0$ and $t_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $y$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}^2$, and not only for $x=vt$, therefore I do not see how we can define $\Delta x/\Delta t$, which I explicitly write as $(x-x_0)/(t-t_0)$, as a well defined velocity, since we cannot consider it as $(x(t)-x(t_0))/(t-t_0)$: $x$ and $t$ can be arbitrarily chosen and $x$ is not a function of $t$...

Moreover, $E$ is a function both of $x$ and $t$ and, even if $x$ were a function of $t$, $\frac{dE(x(t),t)}{dt}$ would not in general be $\frac{\partial E(x,t)}{\partial x}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$ as the expression $P=(\Delta E/\Delta x)(\Delta x/\Delta t)$ would suggest...

Could anybody explain that step to me? I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you rewrote the first formula using the "explicit notation", it is very hard to see what you gained. On one hand, you indicated that $y$ is a function of $x,t$ which would be fine (although it's clearly redundant to write this long expression instead of $y$ all the time) but I can't understand why you wrote $x_0,t_0$ instead of $x,t$.

Even more strangely, you wrote $\Delta x$ as $(x-x_0)$. What you gained by *that* notation is completely unclear to me. $\Delta x$ is just a length of a piece of a string, and you theoretically divide the string to many short pieces whose length is $\Delta x$. If the right side of the piece has the coordinate $x$ and the left side has $x_0$, i.e. if one defines the symbols $x,x_0$ in this way, then it is true that the length of the piece $\Delta x$ may be written as $x-x_0$. But without a specific definition of $x$ and $x_0$, the factor $(x-x_0)$ seems less, and not more, comprehensible than $\Delta x$ as a symbol for the length of the piece of the string.

At any rate, the focus on the question is in a slightly different point, the dependence of $x$ on time in the wave. Well, when a wave packet propagates along a string, then it looks like a localized object and its coordinate $x$ *is* a function of $t$. The velocity of this object – a wave packet – is defined simply as $v=dx/dt$, or $\Delta x /\Delta t$ if one chooses a "bit longer than infinitely short" intervals of time and the corresponding distance.

You must simply imagine that aside from the field theory (partial differential equations etc.) description in terms of $y(x,t)$, there is another description of what's going on – in which you "interpret" the configuration $y(x,t)$ as a wave packet that looks like a localized object and moves along the trajectory $x=x(t)$.

The power of the wave $P$ is the energy that crosses a point on the string per unit time. It's the energy density times the speed of the wave. It's easy to see. Imagine that the energy flows in the form of individual "joules", marbles. If there are $\Delta E / \Delta x$ marbles per unit length and if the marbles move with the speed $v$ to the right, it's obvious that the distance between two marbles is the inverse density, $\Delta s = \Delta x / \Delta E$, and it takes time $\Delta t = \Delta s/v = \Delta x / ( \Delta E v) $ for each marble to get to the point where its neighbor was at the beginning. The inverse of this time $\Delta t$, is the number of marbles per second that are crossing the point, and it's the power $P = v\cdot \Delta E / \Delta x$.

You may also recall that $ P = F \cdot v $ in mechanics. The power (energy per second) is the force times the velocity (inner product). Or you may be careful about the meaning of the symbols in $\Delta E /\Delta x \cdot \Delta x / \Delta t$ and simply cancel the $\Delta x$ to see that this expression is some kind of $\Delta E / \Delta t$, the energy that moves from the "left side of a point" to the "right side of a point" per unit time.

In the considerations above, I needed to imagine that the wave is a "wave packet". But it is always possible to consider a longer or persistent wave. Just interpret such a wave as a "sequence of wave packets". When you to do so, it's important to realize that the speed $v$ could a priori be a phase velocity or the group velocity etc. The wave packets tell you to use the group velocity and it's the relevant velocity by which the energy is actually propagating in the string because even a long wave is ultimately localized (just not as accurately localized) and looks like a wave packet, an object that (in average) moves by the group velocity.

Answer (score 1):

I think here the key point is $dX$ actually means approximate $ds$, the length of the string element. $ds$ is changing as the wave is propagating through the wire in all time $t$, to extend or shrink at a constant speed $\frac{ds}{dt}=v$, does that make sense?

(I happened to read a physics textbook, and noticed the same problem, tried to understand why $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).